# TypeScript: Cannot understand this error: Type: Foo is missing the following properties from type Bar add, addAll, delete, keys, and 3 more

Tags: typescript

I have an interface

```
interface Cache {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string[];
      d: string;
    };
  };
}
```

I want to use it type this object

```
const cache: Cache = {
  a: {
    b: { c: ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3", "stuff4"], d: "irrelevant" }
  }
};
```

However I will get this type errors

> Type '{ a: { b: { c: string[]; d: string; }; }; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Cache': add, addAll, delete, keys, and 3 more.ts(2740)

I can work around this by type casting like

```
const cache = {
  a: {
    b: { c: ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3", "stuff4"], d: "irrelevant" }
  }
} as Cache
```

But I still don't understand why I would have that error.

Also if I found that if I use `type` instead of `interface`

```
type Cache2 = {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string[];
      d: string;
    };
  };
};

const cache2: Cache2 = {
  a: {
    b: { c: ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3", "stuff4"], d: "irrelevant" }
  }
};
```

There is no type error anymore. Can anyone explain the reason to me?

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/cache-type-o0cip?file=/src/index.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a name collision.  There's already an [interface named `Cache`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/135c5082b19f6a3f664cd737e569acd6e87fb852/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L3265-L3279) in the global context to support the [`Cache` Web API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache).  Due to [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), if you declare your own `interface Cache {}` in global scope, you are just *adding* properties/methods to it.  This is not what you want to do.

You should either *rename* `Cache` to something like `MyCache`,

```
interface MyCache {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string[];
      d: string;
    };
  };
}

const myCache: MyCache = {
  a: {
    b: { c: ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3", "stuff4"], d: "irrelevant" }
  }
};
```

or you should declare it inside a different scope, like a `namespace`

```
namespace MyNamespace {
  interface Cache {
    a: {
      b: {
        c: string[];
        d: string;
      };
    };
  }

  const cache: Cache = {
    a: {
      b: { c: ["stuff1", "stuff2", "stuff3", "stuff4"], d: "irrelevant" }
    }
  };
}
```

or a module (which can be signified by `export`ing something in your ts file):

```
export interface Cache {
  a: {
    b: {
      c: string[];
      d: string;
    };
  };
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7&jsx=0&ts=4.0.5#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DCiAWKDeAUMsnAFzL7LEnIBGFRttCFAzmFKAOYDaAugG4azACbtOPYcwC+05HMIzChBAHsQHZAFssuCBQzYEeZAF5KNcpeYNKyVsl4AiDgFcYMAIzOANMlcwDxgAJj8A908AZnDA4IAWZ35-cQDgKCgIABsIADc4cGcFGmVFQggADwAHNSgwZFBIWEQUY1MmUkYRei7mEkcOLhA+IW6SVMGpbsUSRWVVDS0EfQo2lAsO6w6SOypHF0jvWMOw-zjo46DPROTkVOd0zJz8wuLZpWFCEDhtCDYqlpodAAOR+fwBSBsDXA0HgkLWUJIWzGPURfQGkmGAnkfTuEiG3BxtBmxPk836i3qyxMBmQCI23WRuN2DgoByuRzOJ0uwRiXI5NxSFAeGWyeQKYCKylkJWE8yAA)

Answer (score 0):

There is another `Cache` interface defined in Typescript lib `lib.dom.d.ts`

```js
interface Cache {
    add(request: RequestInfo): Promise<void>;
    addAll(requests: RequestInfo[]): Promise<void>;
    delete(request: RequestInfo, options?: CacheQueryOptions): Promise<boolean>;
    keys(request?: RequestInfo, options?: CacheQueryOptions): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Request>>;
    match(request: RequestInfo, options?: CacheQueryOptions): Promise<Response | undefined>;
    matchAll(request?: RequestInfo, options?: CacheQueryOptions): Promise<ReadonlyArray<Response>>;
    put(request: RequestInfo, response: Response): Promise<void>;
}
```

So when you `const cache: Cache = {` it thinks you're trying to use the interface above, that's why changing the name to `Cache2` works.